# listen for multiple streams in background

Tags: flutter, dart

Currently I have two streams implemented in two different widgets I'm listening to. I'm disposing this streams as per best practice when widget is not existent anymore. The problem I'm facing now is, that I want to trigger local notifications whenever new entries are received from db via stream, if my app is in background and/or I'm on another page (where the stream is disposed already). How can I achieve this, without running into memory leakage problems. And where should I place my stream.listen and local notifaction trigger, to have them "globally" available? Hope you understand my question. Otherwise I can add some code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you are not on that page, means you don't require to update UI, then no need of streambuilder, it will work when you are on same screen

Comment: Yes, no need to update UI. But If I'm on another page, and then leave the app,then I will not be notified for incoming data via stream, since it is disposed. What I need is the stream running to trigger my notifcation. Not for UI. How can I achieve this?

Comment: you have to look at the background services now, refer https://medium.com/flutterworld/flutter-perform-background-job-9bce92f0a21e